# Unable to type input into the external console during debugging C++ in VS code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I know I had to set:

```
externalConsole: true
```

in the `launch.json` which I did and also getting the console. But as soon as I step over after the `std::cin` line, I am unable to type anything in the console. It's not taking any input though showing output. What should I do?
Here's my launch.json file:-
`{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

```
{
  "name": "(gdb) Launch",
  "type": "cppdbg",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
  "args": [],
  "stopAtEntry": true,
  "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "environment": [],
  "externalConsole": true,
  "MIMode": "gdb",
  "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
  "setupCommands": [
      {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
      }
  ],
  "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
},
```

]
}
`

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your code.

Comment: I've removed the C++ tag, it'll be relevant to add the error code to the question to get re-tag manually.